# Lightning Network `channel_update` message Flag clarification

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon, lightning-rfc, channels

This is a lnd.log line:

```
2019-01-11 12:20:13.904 [DBG] PEER: Sending ChannelUpdate(chain_hash=000000000019d6689c085ae165831e934ff763ae46a2a6c172b3f1b60a8ce26f, short_chan_id=601495532567724033, flag=256, update_time=2019-01-11 12:19:08 +0100 CET) to 46.229.165.136:9735
```

Since I cannot find a direct correlation with the spec at https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/07-routing-gossip.md 
can someone clarify the "flag" value?

Where can I find the information below?

```
[1:message_flags]
[1:channel_flags]
[2:cltv_expiry_delta]
[8:htlc_minimum_msat]
[4:fee_base_msat]
[4:fee_proportional_millionths]
[8:htlc_maximum_msat] (option_channel_htlc_max)
```

Are they encoded in some way in this "flag"? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `flags` field (2 bytes) has been split into two different (1 byte) fields, the `message_flags` (most significant bits) and the `channel_flags` field (least significant bits). Hence the flags value displayed in `lnd` has the `message_flags` byte set to `0x00` and the `message_flags` set to `0x01`.

`message_flags` indicates that this `channel_update` has some optional fields appended to the end. In this case it has the 0th bit set, which corresponds to the `option_channel_htlc_max` option, hence the `channel_update` has an additional field `htlc_maximum_msat` appended.

Comment: So Basically the "Flag" is a 16 bits field [8 bit message_flag + 8 bit channel_flags]. 

Is it possible to find the others information [cltv_expiry_delta, htlc_minimum_msat, fee_base_msat, fee_proportional_millionths, htlc_maximum_msat] exploring the log or it is only possible by using the lncli getchainifo? 

How can a Node, receiving a channel update message, understand and set the new channel policies?

Comment: Not too familiar with the `lnd` RPC interface, I mostly work on c-lightning. But I guess it should list those with peers as well. And you can set all of these parameters on startup using cli options.